# Anyway of specifying avatar height & width?

Tags: avatar

I'm calling an avatar in a theme with `get_currentuserinfo`. The avatar appears at 96x96 pixel width & height. Changing that size is not problem.

I made a custom function & shortcode to use it in the theme:

```
  function get_loggedin_avatar (){
    global $current_user;
    $result = '';

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        get_currentuserinfo();  
        $result = '<a href="/myaccount">'.
            get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 96, left ).
            '</a>';
    }
    return $result;
}

    add_shortcode( 'loggedinavatar', 'get_loggedin_avatar' );
```

However, whenever I edit the thumbnail image settings a specific way, the avatar is affected. I make set the thumbnail to have a width of 0 and a height of 150, the avatar ouput changes to 96x54. Why is that and how can I edit the thumbnail size without affecting the avatar output?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, since that's pretty internal function that doesn't return anything. Could you maybe provide a short code example?

Comment: Doh - good suggestion, I just updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code how i call the avatar on my posts:

```
 <?php  echo get_avatar( $post->post_author, $size = '150'); ?>
```

You can also define a default avatar if user has no avatar.